# Calculate direction vector

Tags: c++, math, vector

HI All,

How can I calculate direction vector of a line segment, defined by start point (x1, y1) and end point (x2, y2)?

Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

If you want the unit direction vector, divide each component by sqrt((x2 - x1)² + (y2 - y1)²).

Comment: Might want to add something about normalizing.

Answer (score 4):

The direction vector can be represented as (x2 - x1)i + (y2 - y1)j where i and j are unit vectors along x and y axis respectively.

cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you want the vector from the end of vector (x1,y1) to the end of vector (x2,y2), the answer is

```
(x2-x1, y2-y1) + (x1,y1)
```

If you want the (unit-length) direction vector, then the answer is

```
((x2-x1)/L, (y2-y1)/L)
```

where `L=√((x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²)` (thats `$L=\sqrt{(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2}$` in LaTeX).

Comment: @Zinx, Yes a * (x,y) is multiplying a vector by a scalar, which corresponds to dividing each component of the vector by a.